# passing values into as_json via options hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I'm trying to pass an object (the current user) to be used when rendering the json for a collection.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @items }
  format.json { render :json => @items.to_a.as_json(:user => current_user) }
end
```

However, this seems to have no effect as options[:user] is nil in the as_json method.

```
JSON_ATTRS = ['id', 'created_at', 'title', 'content']
def as_json(options={})
  # options[:user] is nil!
  attributes.slice(*JSON_ATTRS).merge(:viewed => viewed_by?(options[:user]))
end
```

Anyone know why this doesn't work, or can suggest a more elegant way to have the json renderer be aware of the current user?

Thanks,
Wei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling as_json on an Array (`@items.to_a`), are you sure that is what you want?
If you are trying to call it on your models then you need to do something like `@items.to_a.map{|i| i.to_json(:user => current_user)}`  (and you probably don't need the `to_a`).

And it is `to_json` you should be calling. It will invoke as_json to get your properties, passing along whatever options you provide it with, but return a properly formated json-string (`as_json` returns a ruby object).

Comment: Thanks! to_json was the key. To clarify, the to_a was to prevent an error, ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError (http://osdir.com/ml/RubyonRailsTalk/2010-08/msg00176.html).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if you want to pass the options on down to "child" associations, I found that this worked (at least on a mongo_mapper backed project):

```
def as_json(options={})
  {
      :field1   => self.field1,
      :field2   => self.field2,
      :details  => self.details.map{|d| d.to_json(options)}
  }
end
```